# How can I make the Uploaded field editable for Media Library?

Tags: media-library, post-editor

The 'uploaded' date field for Media Library entries is read only. Is there a way to make it editable from the Attachment Details window in upload.php?

I've tried the following code as a plug-in. It looks like I'm half way there. This gives me the the Uploaded Date as an input field (good).

However, I can see that I am not hooking into the proper function to actually write that value back to wp_posts along with the other post fields.

SO: How do I hook my input field so that it is part of the object that updates wp_posts?

```
function jch_attachment_fields_to_edit( $form_fields, $post ){

    $post_date =  $post->post_date;

    $form_fields['post_date'] = array(
            'value' => $post_date ? $post_date : '',
            'label' => __( 'Uploaded Date' )
        ); 


    return $form_fields;
}
add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'jch_attachment_fields_to_edit', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Update attachment metadata 
 *
 * @param int $post_ID Attachment ID.
   // this actually works, but only when the user clicks 'Edit more details'
 */


function jch_edit_attachment( $attachment_id ){
        $post_ID = $_REQUEST['post_ID'];

if ( isset( $_REQUEST['attachments'][$attachment_id]['media_date'] ) ) {
  $media_date = $_REQUEST['attachments'][$attachment_id]['media_date'];
    $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE $wpdb->posts SET post_date = %s WHERE ID = %s", $media_date, $post_ID));

    }

}
add_action( 'edit_attachment', 'jch_edit_attachment' );
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please show some research effort so that someone can jump onto the problem with interest. Please remember, problem is _mine_, nobody feels interest in _my_ problem. Let _them_ allure to your problem. :) `wp-admin/includes/template.php` has the date fields available in post edit form, and `wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php` where the media date fields are... let us know how you tried to achieve something... good luck.

Comment: Added my first attempt at a solution. Can someone chime in on this?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you called `global $wpdb` at the top of your function to access the `$wpdb` class. However, I'm not sure you're actually even getting to that part in your `edit_attachment` callback.

You are trying to access the `'media_date'` property of the request, but looks like you are actually setting the name of the input to `'post date'`. You're also using `$post_id` and not `$attachment_id` in your function.

Here's your code cleaned up, hopefully this works for you.

```
function jch_attachment_fields_to_edit( $form_fields, $post ){

    $post_date =  $post->post_date;

    $form_fields['post_date'] = array(
        'value' => $post_date ? $post_date : '',
        'label' => __( 'Uploaded Date' )
    ); 


    return $form_fields;
}
add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'jch_attachment_fields_to_edit', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Update attachment metadata 
 *
 * @param int $post_ID Attachment ID.
 */


function jch_edit_attachment( $attachment_id ){

    if ( empty( $_REQUEST['attachments'][$attachment_id]['post_date'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $date = $_REQUEST['attachments'][$attachment_id]['post_date'];

    // Make sure the date is in the correct format here... Sanitize as well...

    wp_update_post([
        'ID'            => $attachment_id,
        'post_date'     => $date,
        'post_date_gmt' => get_gmt_from_date( $date )
    ]);

}
add_action( 'edit_attachment', 'jch_edit_attachment' );
```

You're going to want to make sure whatever date is going into the DB is going to be in the correct format, so you'll want some validation as well.

Comment: This 'sort of' works. If I edit a date in the Attachment Details popup -and- edit one of the 'regular' fields such as 'Caption', the date is saved. If I only edit the date, whatever action is needed to trigger the 'Save' system doesn't happen. So I need to figure out how to trigger that.

If I click on the 'Edit More Details' link and edit the date in there: When I click the 'Update' button, the 'Working' spinner gets stuck in an infinite loop somehow. So I need to figure out how to stop the infinite loop.

Comment: Another thing you can try which I have actually done in the past is to make a separate meta field (i.e. `_alt_upload_date`) that tracks the user-configured upload date and then use filters and adjust queries to use that where needed (i.e. "Posted On"). That way you don't have to mess with WP's defaults of storing and using the post_date for attachments. Otherwise I'm sure you can get this to work with a little more tweaking and debugging.